# Kafka Listener Container continues processing poll records after exceeding the time defined in `max.poll.interval.ms`

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We seem to have detected what appears to be erroneous behaviour.

Given the following scenario: a consumer reads messages from a topic with only one partition and performs a poll of 10 records. While processing the records one by one, it exceeds the `max.poll.interval.ms` at record 3, so the kafka broker disconnects the consumer and the associated consumer group, but still the consumer thread (Listener Container) continues to process the poll of records up to record 10.

Also, if instead of one instance of the application for example there are two, the moment app1 exceeds `max.poll.interval.mx` and disconnects from the broker, app2 gets the topic partition and starts processing the same poll of records, so both instances of the same application would be processing the same records at the same time (since app1 would continue processing the poll even if it was disconnected from the broker).

If this behaviour is confirmed we think it is inappropriate, since if during the consumer's poll() it exceeds the `max.poll.interval.ms` and is disconnected from the broker, it should stop processing immediately to avoid duplicate processing.

Below are the logs from the previous case of an application instance that exceeds the `max.poll.interval.ms`:

```
2023-03-13T09:23:11.413+01:00  INFO 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-2, groupId=my-group] Resetting offset for partition topic1-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)], epoch=0}}.
2023-03-13T09:23:11.414+01:00  INFO 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$2  : my-group: partitions assigned: [topic1-0]
2023-03-13T09:23:11.424+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : [topic1-0@0, topic1-0@1, topic1-0@2, topic1-0@3, topic1-0@4, topic1-0@5, topic1-0@6, topic1-0@7, topic1-0@8, topic1-0@9]
2023-03-13T09:23:11.425+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@0
2023-03-13T09:23:21.441+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@1
2023-03-13T09:23:31.443+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@2
2023-03-13T09:23:31.480+01:00  WARN 10760 --- [read | my-group] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-2, groupId=my-group] consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

at this point the `max.poll.interval.ms` is exceeded by processing record 3, whereupon the Kafka broker disconnects the consumer and the group. But the consumer continues to process the poll of records, but this time it does not matter if it exceeds the `max.poll.interval.ms` again, it will finish processing all 10 records...

```
2023-03-13T09:23:41.444+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@3
2023-03-13T09:23:51.445+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@4
2023-03-13T09:24:01.447+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@5
2023-03-13T09:24:11.449+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@6
2023-03-13T09:24:21.450+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@7
2023-03-13T09:24:31.451+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@8
2023-03-13T09:24:41.453+01:00 TRACE 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Processing topic1-0@9
```

Once it has processed the 10 records in the poll, it will try to commit the offsets, but it is unable to do so because it is no longer part of the group.

```
2023-03-13T09:24:51.460+01:00  INFO 10760 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-2, groupId=my-group] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group
```

If there is another instance of the same application with the same group, the same records will be reprocessed.

Do you think this is wrong behaviour?

Spring Boot 3.0.4 + Spring Cloud 2022.0.2

Answer (score 1):

This works as designed (by Kafka, not Spring); the container does not know about the loss of the partitions until the next poll is executed.

Best practice is to avoid the condition.

Comment: It is a disadvantage that this information, that the consumer is already disconnected, is not propagated from the Kafka client to spring-kafka... because if this happens, the KafkaMessageListenerContainer could be processing records in duplicate...

It would be interesting that, at least, when pausing/stopping the binding from acutator with SCS, the KafkaMessageListenerContainer would take into account the state of the bindings to continue processing records, something that currently would only be taken into account in the next poll(). Would it be possible?

Comment: It is not possible, the container is constrained by the API that the `Kafka-clients` provides. As I said, best practice is to avoid a forced rebalance. In any case, your code must deal with duplicate deliveries. Kafka only provides “at least once” semantics.

Comment: I don't mean exceeding the `max.poll.interval.ms`... I mean that during the poll() processing, if the consumer binding is paused/stopped from Spring Cloud Stream, the Listener Container keeps processing the poll of records until the end, even if the bindings state is paused/stopped. If you take into account the state of the binding, in some cases you could minimize the impact I detailed in the initial question with a manual action by the user...

Comment: I mean for example pausing the binding from the actuator endpoint that Spring cloud Stream offers... I understand that the Listener Container, during record processing, could query that state... would that make sense?

Comment: There is no such API (to query the "state"), the rebalance is only detected on the next `poll()`.